# shutdown a multithread winform c# app without blocking UI thread

Tags: multithreading, shutdown

I wait for those thread to finish in the close event handler of the main form, but the UI thread is blocked, is there a better solution?

this is the code snippet:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Thread _worker;
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _worker.Join();

    }
```

I hope to display a progress form waiting for the worker thread to complete, how to do this?

Comment: We're going to need a code example of what you mean

Comment: How your application wait for others thread? please share your code.

Comment: @Pongsathon.keng, code shared

Answer (score 0):

You join _worker thread to current thread(UI thread). this is a reason why UI get hung.

If you want to _worker complete before application to be closed, i would like propose following idea.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        // Check worker thread complete or not
        if (_worker.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Not complete, please wait");
        }
}
```

i hope this will work for you.

Comment: I hope display a progress form waiting for the thread to complete, how to do this?